# Configure WCF where ServiceContract and service implementation are in separate assemblies

Tags: c#, wcf, namespaces, app-config, wcf-endpoint

I've looked at a lot of questions on this site that discuss, but don't directly answer this question. I have the following:

In `Library.dll`:

```
namespace LibraryNamespace
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void Operation();
    }
}
```

In `Implementation.dll`:

```
namespace ImplementationNamespace
{
    public class ServiceImplementation : IService
    {
        public void Operation()
        {
            // Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

In `app.config`:

```
<service name="ImplementationNamespace.ServiceImplementation">
    <endpoint 
        address="ServiceImplementation" 
        binding="netTcpBinding" 
        contract="LibraryNamespace.IService" />
    ....
</service>
```

And I keep having a warning with `contract="LibraryNamespace.IService"`. The program runs, but I have a feeling this warning is causing me more problems down the line.

> The 'contract' attribute is invalid - The value
>   'LibraryNamespace.IService' is invalid according to its datatype
>   'serviceContractType' - The Enumeration constraint has failed.

It works when the `ServiceContract` and the service implementation are in the same assembly and namespace, but for some reason, it doesn't work here. How can I reference it properly?

Comment: Why do you want to have them in separate dll? any specific reason?

Comment: Yes, basically, I want to create a generic ServiceContract, and then have write many other ServiceImplementation classes in different assemblies which all follow the same service contract. This way, I can standardize my ServiceImplementations, and call them in a standard way from the client.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure Why do you want to have the contract and implementation in separate dll? any specific reason? Generally they will be in same assembly and so in config file you can refer them with ease. One way to solve this is creating the service endpoint at runtime like below.

In your hosting project refer both the dll `Library.dll` and `Implementation.dll` and have the below code to add the endpoint

```
using LibraryNamespace;
using ImplementationNamespace;

// Specify a base address for the service
String baseAddress = "http://localhost/ServiceImplementation";

// Create the tcp binding
NetTcpBindings tcp = new NetTcpBindings();

// Define service and Create the endpoint
 using(ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceImplementation)))
 {
  host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService),tcp, baseAddress);
 }
```